# Aliens force wife to kill husband. Instead she puts him in suspended animation

Tags: story-identification, novel, spaceship

Can you help me find a space travel Novel from the late 80s to early 90s?

The novel started with a generational space ship leaving earth and heading for its long journey to wherever.  The only two people awake on the ship were a husband and wife.  Since they had the ship to themselves and had to procreate, they were running around naked.  Their fun is interrupted when they are stopped by aliens.  The aliens demand the woman kill her mate.  She puts him in suspended animation instead, then tells the aliens she killed him.  Any ideas?